# How to create a Discord channel with parent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot in discord.js. I have a function that does this:

```js
function createChannel() {
  randomString = crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex');
  const randomCategory = message.guild.channels.create(randomString, {
    type: 'category',
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: message.guild.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ],
  });

  message.guild.channels.create(randomString, {
    type: 'text',
    parent: randomCategory.id,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: message.guild.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ],
  });

  message.guild.channels.create(randomString, {
    type: 'voice',
    parent: randomCategory.id,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: message.guild.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

This should create a category, and populate it with a voice and text channel with the same name. However, when I run it the channels don't get their parent set correctly.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for randomCategory.parentID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guild.channels.create` returns a promise so you either need to use the `.then()` method or async-await to get `randomCategory`. At the moment it's just a pending promise, not the returned category:

```js
// make the function an async function
async function createChannel() {
  randomString = crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex');
  // use await to wait the promise to resolve
  const randomCategory = await message.guild.channels.create(randomString, {
    type: 'category',
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: message.guild.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ],
  });

  message.guild.channels.create(randomString, {
    type: 'text',
    // pass the randomCategory object, not just the id
    parent: randomCategory,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: message.guild.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ],
  });

  message.guild.channels.create(randomString, {
    type: 'voice',
    // pass the randomCategory object, not just the id
    parent: randomCategory,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: message.guild.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

It seems to be working fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create), you should pass the channel as a parent instead of the id. You should probably also await the category creation before making the children.

```js
async function createChannel(){
    const randomString = crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex'); //added const here since you're never overwriting
    const randomCategory = await message.guild.channels.create(randomString, { 
        type: 'category', 
        permissionOverwrites: [{ 
            id: message.guild.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        }]
    });
    
    await message.guild.channels.create(randomString, {
        type: 'text', 
        parent: randomCategory,
        permissionOverwrites: [{ 
            id: message.guild.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        }]
    });
    
    await message.guild.channels.create(randomString, { 
        type: 'voice', 
        parent: randomCategory,
        permissionOverwrites: [{ 
            id: message.guild.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        }]
    });
}
```